# ASP.NET Cookie & JWT Hybrid Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

The application is setup to authenticate users using external login providers resulting in a standard ASPNET identity cookie which is used to authorize all non-API endpoints. API endpoints use JWT Bearer authentication to take care of CSRF (see setup below). My question is about the way API-Clients (Blazor) exchange their identity auth cookie for a JWT. The method is so simple that its almost too simple and I think you should never be above questioning your security decisions. So, do you see anything wrong with this token exchange endpoint on a MVC controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a JWT for the cookie-authorized user
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("token")]
public IResult Token()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User;

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: appSettings.JwtConfig.Issuer,
        audience: appSettings.JwtConfig.Audience,
        notBefore: DateTime.Now,
        claims: user.Claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(jwtKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

    return Results.Json(new
    {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt),
        expires = jwt.ValidTo
    });
}
```

Auth Setup:

```
const string CustomAuthScheme = "hybrid";

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CustomAuthScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CustomAuthScheme;
    })
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddApple(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddPolicyScheme(CustomAuthScheme, CustomAuthScheme, options =>
    {
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = ctx =>
        {
            // make API requests require a JWT, everything else a Cookie
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                return JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            return IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Remember that this is a simple GET request so no pre-flight check from the browser. If the cookie is set as same-site strict or lax, though, the cookie will not be sent from a different origin. (a CSRF attack would originate from a different domain, so you should be good... just confirm that the cookie is set same-site strict or lax) The returned token would be vulnerable to XSS, so be sure to mitigate against that.

Comment: The endpoint does not return the JWT as a cookie but as a JSON response.

Comment: right... it takes a cookie (or maybe credentials through negotiate) that would have been set http-only, so the cookie is reasonably safe from XSS.  The JWT will be persisted client-side and available to script.  Which is why it's vulnerable to XSS attack.

Comment: As a security  best practice, the JWT token you're generating has a relatively short expiration time of 15 minutes. Consider adjusting the token's expiration based on your security requirements and the user experience.Ensure that you have proper validation in place for incoming requests to this endpoint. You should validate that the request indeed comes from an authenticated user with a valid cookie-based ASP.NET Identity session.Make sure that this endpoint is only accessible to authenticated users who possess a valid identity cookie.restrict access based on user roles or claims if necessary.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal All of the pre-conditions you've mentioned are in place.